# Operators in Perl

Tags: perl, operators

Sorry for asking this question.I know Perl operators are very importance while writing Perl script.Can any one provide me all Perl operators with examples or else give any links for my case

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html

Comment: Perl 6 has over 150 of them. That's more than is reasonable to reproduce in a Stackoverflow answer.

Comment: if possible give links

Answer (score 3):

See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). If you have Perl installed, you can read this from the command line with `perldoc perlop` (unless you have one of those idiotic distributions Linux distros that removed the `perldoc` program).

To learn more about Perl in general, start reading `perldoc perltoc` (table of contents) for Perl and `perldoc perlintro`.